# Separator style like iPad settings app

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I need to make a table view with separators like the table view in the master view controller of the iPad Settings app. The separators in the table view has a white shadow and it seems that the separator is half transparent.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this effect? I would prefer doing it in a static table view.

[image: Separators in Settings app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they've used a section header view with a gradient background. Implement this method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Create a gradient 1px wide and whatever height you need tall. Create a view using that gradient as a background (it should tile horizontally) and return your custom view in that method (assuming the `section` passed to the method is correct).

You'll need to implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` too for this to work correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear. What I meant was not the section header. It's the separator between the cells.

Comment: For the separator, use a custom background image with a 1px or 2px gradient at the bottom of the image. You can make the image tile horizontally and give this effect nicely. There is a way to do this in code I think, but the background image is simple and looks good.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm not sure it can be done in that way if I cannot set the background of an "empty cell" (cells used for filling out the table view. Do you know if there is a way to do this when the table view is create statically?